# Content owned by members

Tags: umbraco, umbraco8

I'm trying to work out the best way to have content owned by members (one member has many properties). I tried using relationships but these don't seems fully featured yet and I've also used a member picker on the property which works fine.

What I'm missing is being able to see all owned properties for each member from the members tab (along with the ability to edit/view) from the back office.

Is there a way to do this using the member picker field or do I need to use relationships?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the `EditorModel` events to do this. You can use these events to interfere which data will be send to the backend. If you want to e.g. hide tabs, this an easy way to do so.

You can read more about this in the documentation about [EditorModel Events](https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/Reference/Events/EditorModel-Events/).

Or if you do not want to do everything yourselves, check out the [Plumber package](https://our.umbraco.com/packages/backoffice-extensions/plumber-workflow-for-umbraco/). It might not do exactly what you want, but it will bring you very far i guess.